# Frequency of variables selection using elastic net

Tags: r, lasso

I am using elastic net regression on a dataset with quite a small number of observations (clinical risk scores) and large number (1000+) of potential predictor variables (gene expression values). The ultimate aim is to identify variables (genes) that could be explored further experimentally.

However, I noticed that the variables being selected (e.g. coefficients not equal to zero) vary when I leave out a single observation from the dataset (some are maintained, some drop, some are added in), and I would like get some more confidence regarding which variables are relatively robust to such changes.

1. Would it be methodologically acceptable to generate either jackknife or bootstrap datasets from my original dataset, and repeat the whole model selection procedure (e.g. repeated selection of tuning parameters based on cross validation and the associated model) for each of these datasets, and then for each of those models determine how often a variable was selected?
2. Would it be acceptable to re-run a linear regression analysis with sets of selected genes of decreasing frequency of selection (e.g. only use the top 3 genes selected most often, or the top 4 etc), and select the cut-off of frequency of selection of genes based on the cross validation metrics I get for each of these models? If I do this I see a sort of leveling of cross validation prediction error metrics after a certain point (e.g. adding further variables does not help to reduce prediction error metrics). This second approach feels like a "wrong" thing to do. However, it is just to determine a threshold of which subset of selected genes I want to focus on further.